# Iterate through map for file function

Tags: terraform

I have a usecase for uploading multiple files to s3 using terraform. I would like to upload multiple objects using the count function. In doing this need to iterate through the source with file("${path.module}/path/to/file").

Is there anyway to make the file function a mapped variable leveraging the count.index?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Terraform 0.12.8 introduced a new function [`fileset`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/fileset.html) which can return a set of file paths matching a particular pattern in a particular base directory.

We can combine that with resource `for_each` (rather than `count`) to upload the matching files to S3, like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "example" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/files", "*") # could use ** instead for a recursive search

  bucket       = "example"
  key          = each.value
  source       = "${path.module}/${each.value}"

  # Unless the bucket has encryption enabled, the ETag of each object is an
  # MD5 hash of that object.
  etag = filemd5("${path.module}/${each.value}")
}
```

Using `for_each` instead of `count` here means that Terraform will identify each instance of the resource by its S3 path rather than by its position in a list, and so you can add and remove files without disturbing other files. For example, if you have a file called `example.txt` then Terraform will track its instance as `aws_s3_object.example["example.txt"]`, rather than an address like `aws_s3_object.example[3]` where 3 is its position in the list of files.

---

I have written a Terraform module that builds on `fileset` to also support template rendering and detecting filetypes based on filename suffixes, which might make life easier in some more complicated situations: [`apparentlymart/dir/template`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/apparentlymart/dir/template). You can use its result with `aws_s3_object` in a similar way to the above, as shown in its README.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question! Thank you for your help!